# * Triangle Pattern design issue

Tags: c++, loops

I am relatively new to programming and am facing a small dilemma, I am trying to print a triangle like this:

```
     *
    **
   ***
  ****
 *****
```

The idea behind the program is that the user is prompted for the number of rows, so in this example they would have input 5 as the number of rows.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main(){

int i, j, rows;

    printf("Enter the maximum number of stars (between 1 and 10 inclusive):\n");
    scanf("%d",&rows);

    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=10-i; j++) // for space
        printf(" ");

        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

It is close to getting the correct spacing however all the '*' characters start 5 spaces indented.

```
 _____    *
 _____   **
 _____  ***
 _____ ****
 _____*****
```

where the _ represents a space, I am not sure how to fix this, I want it to start at the far left hand side of the execution window.

Happy to elaborate on the question if required.

Cheers.

Comment: Consider the magic number `10` in your code. Why is it 10?

Comment: Why are you running to `10` in `for (j=1; j<=10-i; j++)`?  Shouldn't that be 5(equal to the number of rows)?

Comment: not related, but I strongly encourage you to get used to iterating from 0, it will make your life easier in the long run

Comment: @Biffen It is at 10 because the input is limited to a number between 1 and 10

Comment: @Summ0102 That won't make the number 10 at all times though.

Comment: I don't really know what you try, but it is possible that you want to do for (j=1; j<=rows-i; j++) instead of for (j=1; j<=10-i; j++)

Comment: @Alexi that worked a treat, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There are spaces before your input that are generated by the loop:

```
for (j=1; j<=10-i; j++) // for space
printf(" ");
```

Note that this loop runs to 10 *no matter what is contained in `rows`*.

To fix the code you'd need to make your maximum `rows`, *not* the `10` in the loop.

That said, you're using C++, so I'd recommend that you use the language, this is a very simple problem for [`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
int rows;

cin >> rows;

for(auto i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
    cout << setw(rows) << string(i, '*') << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/JBRyaY)